# Why is 'this' keyword required inside constructor function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object, scope, this

I am trying to instantiate a constructor function using the new keyword in JavaScript. However, it is not working as expected -

```
var a = function () {
            abc = function () {
                      return  "abc";
                  }
        }

var obj = new a();
```

If I do -

`obj.a();` . It says -

```
Uncaught TypeError: obj.abc is not a function
```

But if I just access it without the object `obj`, it works

```
abc();
```

But the whole problem is resolved if I use `this` for the inner function -

```
var a = function () {
            this.abc = function () {
                           return  "abc";
                       }
        }
```

So my question is, if I declare `abc()` without 'this' keyword, isn't its scope inside the `a` function. Why is it being treated like a global function when it is declared inside the function `a` ?

Comment: When you do `obj.a()` it says *"__obj.abc__ is not a function"*?! Please double check your names here.

Comment: Edited. It was typo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> if I declare abc() without this keyword, isn't its scope inside the a() function. Why is it being treated like a global function when it is declared inside the function a ?

It isn't *declared* anywhere. The code in `a` assigns to an undeclared variable, which creates an *implicit global* (in loose mode, the default).

This is one of many good reasons to use strict mode (`"use strict";` at the top of the script). In strict mode, assigning to an undeclared variable is an error (just like reading from an undeclared variable is). More in my blog post [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html).

---

And yes, as you've discovered, `this.` is never optional in JavaScript as it is in Java or C#. To refer to the instance being created within `a` when you do `new a()`, you must use `this`.

Side note: The overwhelming convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions (functions you call via `new`) start with a capital letter. So `A` rather than `a`, or perhaps `Example`:

```js
var Example = function () {
    this.abc = function(){
        return "abc";
    };
};

var obj = new Example();
console.log(obj.abc());
```

You might consider putting `abc` on the prototype rather than recreating it on every call to `a`:

```js
var Example = function () {
};
Example.prototype.abc = function(){
    return "abc";
};

var obj = new Example();
console.log(obj.abc());
```

Or with ES2015+ `class` syntax:

```js
class Example {
    abc(){
        return "abc";
    }
}

var obj = new Example();
console.log(obj.abc());
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you haven't declared `abc` as a property of the newly constructed object - you're making it into a globally available function by omitting the `var` keyword. If you want to make it accessible without using `this`, try this:

```js
var a = function() {
  var abc = function() {
    return "abc";
  }
  return { abc };
}

var obj = new a();
console.log(obj.abc());
```

Comment: Why create and return a new object (which doesn't have `a.prototype` as its prototype) from `a` when `a` is already being called via `new`, and so a new object (with the correct prototype) has already been created? All th eOP needs to do is what they shows in their question: `this.abc = function() { /*...*/ };`.

Comment: "*That's because you haven't declared abc as a property…*", you mean as a **variable**, properties are created. ;-)

Comment: *(OMG the number of typos in my comment above. **sigh**)*

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable/function without any keywork will make it a global one:

```js
abc();

abc = function() {
  console.log('global abc');
};

// same as:
//window.abc = function() {...};
window.abc();
```

Using `let` and your function will be scoped:

```js
{
  let abc = function() {
    console.log('let abc');
  }
}

abc(); // ReferenceError: abc is not defined
```

If you declare a function with `var`, you will be able to execute it even after closure end, but not before, and if not declared insinde a function:

```js
//abc(); // TypeError: abc is not a function

{
  var abc = function() {
    console.log('var abc');
  }
}

abc(); // will work

let a = function() {
  var cde = function() {
    console.log('var cde');
  }
  
  cde(); // will work
}

cde(); // ReferenceError: cde is not defined
```

Finally, `this` will make a object property:

```js
let a = function() {
    this.abc = function() {
      console.log('this.abc');
    };
}

let obj = new a();
obj.abc();

a.abc(); // TypeError: abc is not a function
```

Comment: Hello, I wanted to know why is this needed inside constructor function ? If I don't use this, the inner function is being assigned to global scope. why ?

Comment: Look at [T.J. Crowder 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55685805/5878071). It is well explained.